# datamapper multi-field unique index

Tags: ruby, indexing, datamapper

In Datamapper, how would one specify the the combination of two fields must be unique. For example categories must have unique names within a domain:

```
class Category
  include DataMapper.resource
  property :name, String, :index=>true #must be unique for a given domain

  belongs_to :domain
end
```

Comment: Somewhere I saw mentioned that named keys will group like this.  ie :unique_index=>:name for both name and domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to define both properties as keys? Not sure I have tried it but that way they should become a composite key.

```
property :name, String, :key => true    
property :category, Integer, :key => true
```

Comment: Actually there already is a key, I just didn't include it in the code snippet.

Answer (score 16):

You have to create a unique index for the two properties:

```
class Category
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :name, String, :unique_index => :u
  property :domain_id, Integer, :unique_index => :u

  belongs_to :domain
end
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it will require that both name and domain be unique across the table.  What I asked was how to make the set (:name, :domain) unique.

Comment: Indeed, although the `:u` symbol could have been clearer -- for example `:index_on_name_and_domain_id` -- it actually is correct. See the section Indices on the DataMapper property documentation page: http://rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/master/DataMapper/Property. The statements create a multi-column composite unique index.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, John, Joschi's answer is correct: the use of named :unique_index values does create a multiple-column index; it's important to read the right-hand side of those hash-rockets (i.e., if it had just been `true`, you would be right).

Comment: I've moved away from DataMapper so this may have changed, but at the time I wrote the comment, it was correct.